# Why is this the average of a Ball/Sphere?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a textbook that defines the following notation (sorry for using an image I don;t know how to typeset the integral symbol on SE):

[image]

How is that first term derived?

The text doesn't say but I assume $n$ is the dimension on which the ball is derived, but what is $\alpha$?

My intuition tells me that the denominator of that fraction should be equal to the volume of the sphere so I assume $\alpha$ is an expression of $\pi$ and $n$?

Comment: The equations say $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of a unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: To me these seem analogous to the average value of a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]:f_{ave}=[1/(b-a)]\int_a^b f(x) dx$

Comment: "I have a textbook" is rather useless information! Why not say *which* book it is? Anyway, this looks like it's coming from Appendix A in Evans's PDE book, where the notation $\alpha(n)$ is explained on the previous page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average of a function over any set is always defined as the integral of the function divided by the measure of the set (i.e area/volume). Let's consider the first equation:
\begin{align}
\text{average}(f,B(x,r))&:=\frac{1}{\text{vol}_n(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}f\,dy.
\end{align}
What is the volume of $B(x,r)$? Well, the volume doesn't depend on the center, and it scales like $r^n$, so it is $r^n\cdot\text{vol}_n(B(0,1))$ (the subscript $n$ indicates we're talking about $n$-dimensional volume). Evans uses the shorthand notation $\alpha(n):=\text{vol}_n(B(0,1))$ for the volume of the unit ball, which if you want an explicit expression, it is $\alpha(n)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{n\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$.

Similarly, for the second equation,
\begin{align}
\text{average}(f,\partial B(x,r))&:=\frac{1}{\text{vol}_{n-1}(\partial B(x,r))}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}f\,dS.
\end{align}
What's the surface area of a sphere? Well, it doesn't depend on its center $x$, and it scales like $r^{n-1}$, so it is $r^{n-1}\text{vol}_{n-1}(\partial B(0,1))$. Now, it turns out that the surface area of the unit sphere is $\frac{1}{n}$ times the volume of the unit ball (e.g compare $2\pi r$ vs $4\pi r^2$, or $4\pi r^2$ vs $\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3$); if this is not obvious, you should verify this directly by computing the volume of the unit ball by switching to polar coordinates and using Fubini's theorem. Thus, the surface area of $\partial B(x,r)$ is $r^{n-1}\cdot n\alpha(n)$.